# live.js doesn't reload css when combined with prefixfree

Tags: javascript, html, css, page-refresh, vendor-prefix

I am writing a simple HTML page and using [live.js](http://livejs.com/) for page and css reloading whenever the page was changed. But when I include [-prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/) to the page the styles are no longer reloaded automatically.

Is there any way to fix this?

Example:

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="prefixfree.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="live.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="colored">
   some text
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#colored {
  background: blue;
}
```

What I do is changing the color. It works until prefixfree is included.

Comment: Do you have the page where this is happening in that we can look at?

Comment: @SeanKeating this is happening on my local server. Example in the question is enough to reproduce this. Reloading happens when you change the color and save the file so you have to test it locally too.

Comment: I don't see your problem with the information you provided. http://jsfiddle.net/MFAmL/

Comment: Seems like you're doing it wrong. Jsfiddle won't help here because there is nothing for live.js to reload. Here is what its homepage says: Just include Live.js and it will monitor the current page including local CSS and Javascript by sending consecutive HEAD requests to the server. Changes to CSS will be applied dynamically and HTML or Javascript changes will reload the page.

So it's aimed at using local web server or uploading your files to remote server whenether you save it. Also the style must be placed in a separate file instead of inlining.

Comment: There is a demo http://livejs.com/demo. It may help to better understand the purpose of live.js

Answer (score 1):

I made a [CSSrefresh](http://cssrefresh.frebsite.nl/) fork supporting prefix-free:

https://github.com/yukulele/CSSrefresh

Answer (score 1):

I have made a LiveJS fork supporting prefixfree, based on yukulélé code :P

https://github.com/newhope/live.js

Comment: I currently don't work with html anymore. So if a few other people check this, I'll accept this answer